# jQuery change selected using two attributes (e.g. class and value)

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, selected

I have a `<select>` where options can have same value but with different class. Is it possible to change selected option based on those two elements together?

eg:

```
<select id="select">
  <option class="ABC" value="99">Option 1</option>
  <option class="DEF" value="99">Option 2</option>
  <option class="ABC" value="98">Option 3</option>
  <!-- ....... -->
</select>

if(var === null) {
  $('#select option[class="ABC" value="99"]').prop('selected', true);
}
```

This is what I tried, but doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two attribute selectors, not multiple attributes in one selector.

```
$('#select option[class="ABC"][value="99"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Also, the normal way to match a class is with `.ABC`, so this should be written as

```
$('#select option.ABC[value="99"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: It works. I guess the quote after `'#select'` should be at the end of closing parenthesis `('#select .............. ]')`, mine was wrong too